# Magento 2 - Unable to access the Category page without index.php

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2.3

I have Magento 2.3.0 recently upgraded. In which, I removed index.php from the base url, every where its working fine.

Even in Category Page, except for one category page.

I can only access that page using index.php only. unless its showing as 404 error.

Can any one guess about the issue.?

Comment: check htaccess.

Comment: There is no specific code in htaccess for any category

Comment: mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Take the backup of the url_rewrite table, and truncate it. Then reindex data. It may help.

Comment: Its Working @MohitKumarArora . But All URLs changed now.. Unable to regenerate it. How to do it.?

Comment: If you have custom URL rewrite in that table, then the above method will create problems which you have mentioned.

Comment: First, restore the previous data from the table back up. Then find the URL rewrites of that particular category only and delete those rows from the table. Finally, do the reindexing of the data. Please share what effect it makes.

Comment: Issue seems to be something strange. U know, after I deleted the rewrite Url record of that particular category, url seems to be like this. www.mystore.com/catalog/category/view/s/training/id/12/.. But the actual catgory url was /catalog/category/view/id/12..

Comment: No idea>...??? @MohitKumarArora

Comment: After that, did you do reindexing?

Comment: Yess... reindex and cleared cache. I still don't get it. if I given index.php its working.. How it could be?

Comment: I think there was a conflict with the URL name training.html

I just renamed it as trainin.html its working fine, where us training-mag.html not worked.

Don't know what kind of conflict is it. Since would like to share you guys. 

if anyone had an idea, please share here.

For Note: No problem with htaccess file.